# How to permantly remove submodules in git repository?

Tags: git, dvcs

Several days before, I used the submodule feature of git and added quite a lot of repositories, however I remove all of them now(`git submodule list` returns nothing; also, `.git/config` and the related `.gitmodules` do not contain any of the repository information). But git **do** preserve them: they are still in the directory of **`.git/modules`** directory! What annoys me is that they take disk space even I don't need them at all(also I believe I could re-add them as submodule at any time).

So how can I deal with that? Can I simply remove the directory `.git/modules`?

Comment: Git can handle the case of switching to another branch that does not have that submodule. When you switch back, you do not need to spend time re-cloning the submodule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can `rm -rf .git/modules/XXX`.

Comment: Does this has any side effect? I had a bad experience several days ago when I removed some files in .git directory and then git complained that the repository was destroyed; so I need to ensure that.